# API for Configuring a Default routing setting for a domain

Tags: gmail-api

is there a API way to define new route? As described here: https://support.google.com/a/answer/2368153

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, there is no API or programmatic way to set Default Routing rules.

One thing you can do though is create a default routing rule that triggers off of group membership. Then you can programatically add/remove users to the Google Group in order to modify their routing behavior. [Group membership](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members) can be managed via the Admin SDK Directory API.